# Get "ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException" when executing python script in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I try to execute a python script in Powershell, I get this error. 
The script itself is correct,  I can execute the same command in CMD.

So what should I write in powershell?

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" .\setup.py install
At line:1 char:40
+ "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" .\setup.py install
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '.\setup.py' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: try C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe setup.py install(remove . & \-slash)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put an ampersand in front of your application name (here its python.exe)

```
& "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" .\setup.py install
```

PowerShell needs the ampersand to interpret the string as a filename.